# Python Type_Error: unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python

Hi guys I installed a package and when I tried to use the functions, it said  "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coordinates_type' "

```
OK = OrdinaryKriging(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2], variogram_model='power', verbose=False, enable_plotting=False,coordinates_type='geographic')
z, ss = OK.execute('grid', gridx, gridy)
```

Here is the source code for the function

```
def __init__(self, x, y, z, variogram_model='linear',
             variogram_parameters=None, variogram_function=None, nlags=6,
             weight=False, anisotropy_scaling=1.0, anisotropy_angle=0.0,
             verbose=False, enable_plotting=False, enable_statistics=False,
             coordinates_type='euclidean'):
```

This error only happened with argument coordinates_type, and I had the latest version of the package.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you specify the package and a minimal example?

Comment: The package is PyKrige, here is the link :https://github.com/bsmurphy/PyKrige. An similar example is krige_geometric.py, however it just happened and my friends and I don't why ; (

Comment: always add full error message (Traceback) in question. There are many useful informations.

Comment: did you use name `OrdinaryKriging` to define own class ?

Comment: if I run the example krige_geometric.py, it has the same error. Also if I remove "coordinates_type='geographic' ", the program can be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `coordinates_type` argument is not available on the version of PyKrige currently on pypi (1.3.2). The master branch of the repository you looked at is ahead of the PyPi release. If you look at the "1.3.2" tag of the repository, you will see the argument does not exist and it seems to just assume the coordinates are euclidean.

I am not a GIS person, but the solution sounds like it might be to convert the coordinates before passing them to PyKrige.

Alternatively, you can install the current master from github. But please be aware that the development branches of projects might sometimes be in an broken state:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/bsmurphy/PyKrige
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely helpful ; )